# mysql: sum other join table value based on one table

Tags: php, mysql

My query is to calculate total number of insufficient quantity for each item of a product.

To create a product, I need more than one item. So, I need to check each item is insufficient or not. Then, show the insufficient quantity of each item to user.

In `bpo_require_item` table, there has necessary qty of each item to create a product. If product order is more than one, then same item exists more than one row. (`model_id` means the product.)

```
id | model_id | item_id | item_code | necessary_qty |
1       1           1         I001         2000
2       1           2         I002         2000
3       1           3         I003         1000              
4       2           1         I001         1500
5       2           2         I002         4500
6       2           3         I003         1500  
7       3           1         I001         2500
8       3           2         I002         3750
9       3           3         I003         5000  
10      3           5         I005         6250
```

In `warehouse_item` table, there has remain quantity of each item in real warehouse.

```
id | item_id | item_code | normal_quantity |
 1       1         I001         140
 2       2         I002         120
 3       3         I003         110
 4       5         I005         200
```

And each item have there `safety stock quantity` because if item inside warehouse has reach nearly safety stock then we need to order this item from our supplier. This is `item` table.

```
item_id | item_code | safety_stock_qty |
1         I001         100
2         I002         100
3         I003         100
5         I005         100
```

In `pre_supplier_order` table, we save each require item quantity (but this is not the real order).

```
id | item_id | item_code | order_qty |
 1       1         I001         3460
 2       2         I002         6480
 3       3         I003         2490
```

In `supplier_order_item` table, this is the real order data.

```
id | item_id | item_code | order_qty | date
 1       1         I001         1000     2018-09-25
 2       1         I001         500      2018-09-27
```

> Note: there has another table like `buyer_order` and `supplier_order`,
>   but I not mention specific here because I only need to check
>   `bpo_status='O4'` and `supplier_order` of `spo_status=S1`.

Now, I need to calculate insufficient quantity of each item based on `bpo_require_item` table.

First, sum all same item_id quantity in `bpo_require_item` and then sum all same item_id in `pre_supplier_order` table and `supplier_order_item` table. Then I want to calculate each item with following formula:

```
each item insufficient_qty = ( (warehouse.normal_quantity - item. safety_stock_qty) + pre_supplier_order.order_qty + supplier_order_item.quantity ) - (bpo_require_item.necessary_qty)
```

For the above table data, my expected result for insufficient qty of each item is as follow:

```
item_id ( necessary_qty ) - ((warehouse-safety_stock_qty) + pre_supplier_order + supplier_order_item)) = insufficient_qty
   1        6000                    40                        3460                 1500                    -1000
   2        10250                   20                        6480                                         -3750
   3        7500                    10                        2490                                         -5000
   5        6250                    100                                                                    -6150
```

But, I get wrong result with my query.

```
SELECT *
    FROM (    
    SELECT 
          bri.item_id, bri.item_code, bri.item_name,
          bri.vmc_code, bri.hs_code, itm.safety_stock_qty,
          SUM(bri.necessary_qty) as total_require_item,
          SUM(pre.order_qty) as total_pre_item, 
          SUM(soi.quantity) as total_supplier_order,
          wi.normal_quantity, 
       (
         ( 
           (wi.normal_quantity-itm.safety_stock_qty) + 
               coalesce(SUM(pre.order_qty),0)+
               coalesce(soi.quantity,0) 
              ) - coalesce(SUM(bri.necessary_qty),0)
           ) as insufficient_qty
        FROM `buyer_order` as bo
        LEFT JOIN bpo_require_item as bri ON (bo.po_no = bri.po_no AND bo.bpo_status='O4')
        LEFT JOIN item as itm ON (bri.item_id = itm.item_id AND itm.flag=1)
        LEFT JOIN warehouse_item as wi ON (bri.item_id = wi.item_id)
        LEFT JOIN pre_supplier_order as pre ON (bri.item_id = pre.item_id)
        LEFT JOIN supplier_order_item as soi ON (bri.item_id = soi.item_id)
        LEFT JOIN supplier_order as so ON (soi.supplier_order_id = so.supplier_order_id AND so.spo_status='S1')
     GROUP BY bri.item_id
     ORDER BY bo.po_no, bri.item_id 
    ) as requireItemTable 
    WHERE insufficient_qty < 0
```

I think the problem is `SUM` for each item with `LEFT JOIN` is wrong. But I'm not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Do you need to do it all in mysql? Query that have to do some calcule can take long time, if you know how to calculate what you want, why not get all result then do some calcul with PHP?

Comment: @MickaelLeger Yes, I know how to do in php. But with php I will run (may be) three query at a time. So, if I can, I just want to do it with one query. That why I try with this query.

Comment: Can you post up a fiddle?

Comment: I agree with @MickaelLeger about performing calculations outside of MySQL but you also should simplify your query (for your development and for question here) - it's much easier to comprehend/debug 2-3 simplier queries than 1 sophisticated one. I tried to reproduce your query but logic includes requests to other queries which structure is obscure so please simplify or post a fiddle. Thx